# Como remover acentuações com expressões regulares no Python?

Tags: python, string, regex

Estou desenvolvendo uma expressão regular para tentar substituir acentos e caracteres com ç por caracteres normais

Exemplo:

```
á = a 
ç = c
é = e
```

Porém a minha *regex* está apenas eliminando, alguma dica?

```
import re


string_velha = ("Olá você está ????   ")
string_nova = re.sub(u'[^a-zA-Z0-9: ]', '', string_velha.encode().decode('utf-8'))
print(string_nova)
```

Resultado:

```
Ol voc est
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um modo simples que usa o módulo `unicodedata`, incluído no python, pra decompor cada acento unicode em seu codepoint original + codepoint de combinação, depois filtrar os codepoints de combinação para ter uma string limpa:

```
import unicodedata
string_velha = "Olá você está????"
string_nova = ''.join(ch for ch in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', string_velha) 
    if not unicodedata.combining(ch))
print(string_nova)
```

Resultado:

```
Ola voce esta????
```

Uma outra forma é usar o `unidecode` - esse módulo externo precisa ser instalado, o objetivo dele é justamente gerar uma representação somente-ascii de caracteres unicode. Ele cobre mais possibilidades de caracteres, porém é uma dependência externa.

```
import unidecode
string_nova = unidecode.unidecode(string_velha)
print(string_nova)
```

Comment: Perfeito ,  ficou um código bem limpo e sucinto. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Veja a assinatura da função `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`, o segundo argumento da mesma define a `string` ou `função` que será usada quando o pattern realizar com sucesso uma busca na string original, no seu caso basta implementar uma função que será chamada cada vez que isso ocorrer por exemplo:

```
import re

def repl(match):
    data = {"á": "a", "ç": "c", "ê": "e"}
    return data.get(match.group(0))

string_velha = ("Olá você está ????   ")
string_nova = re.sub(u'[^a-zA-Z0-9: ]', repl, string_velha.encode().decode('utf-8'))
print(string_nova)
```

Answer (score -1):

O seu código está trocando todos os caracteres capturados na expressão regular por '' e assim removendo o acento.

Se quiser traduzir cada acento pelo caractere respectivo sem acento, você pode usar um dicionário normal e fazer o `replace`.

```
import re

# char codes: https://unicode-table.com/en/#basic-latin
accent_map = {
    u'\u00c0': u'A',
    u'\u00c1': u'A',
    u'\u00c2': u'A',
    u'\u00c3': u'A',
    u'\u00c4': u'A',
    u'\u00c5': u'A',
    u'\u00c6': u'A',
    u'\u00c7': u'C',
    u'\u00c8': u'E',
    u'\u00c9': u'E',
    u'\u00ca': u'E',
    u'\u00cb': u'E',
    u'\u00cc': u'I',
    u'\u00cd': u'I',
    u'\u00ce': u'I',
    u'\u00cf': u'I',
    u'\u00d0': u'D',
    u'\u00d1': u'N',
    u'\u00d2': u'O',
    u'\u00d3': u'O',
    u'\u00d4': u'O',
    u'\u00d5': u'O',
    u'\u00d6': u'O',
    u'\u00d7': u'x',
    u'\u00d8': u'0',
    u'\u00d9': u'U',
    u'\u00da': u'U',
    u'\u00db': u'U',
    u'\u00dc': u'U',
    u'\u00dd': u'Y',
    u'\u00df': u'B',
    u'\u00e0': u'a',
    u'\u00e1': u'a',
    u'\u00e2': u'a',
    u'\u00e3': u'a',
    u'\u00e4': u'a',
    u'\u00e5': u'a',
    u'\u00e6': u'a',
    u'\u00e7': u'c',
    u'\u00e8': u'e',
    u'\u00e9': u'e',
    u'\u00ea': u'e',
    u'\u00eb': u'e',
    u'\u00ec': u'i',
    u'\u00ed': u'i',
    u'\u00ee': u'i',
    u'\u00ef': u'i',
    u'\u00f1': u'n',
    u'\u00f2': u'o',
    u'\u00f3': u'o',
    u'\u00f4': u'o',
    u'\u00f5': u'o',
    u'\u00f6': u'o',
    u'\u00f8': u'0',
    u'\u00f9': u'u',
    u'\u00fa': u'u',
    u'\u00fb': u'u',
    u'\u00fc': u'u'
}

def accent_remove (m):
  return accent_map[m.group(0)]

string_velha = "Olá você está ????   "
string_nova = re.sub(u'([\u00C0-\u00FC])', accent_remove, string_velha.encode().decode('utf-8'))

print(string_nova)
```

Coloquei no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DimwittedMistyScale) para ver rodando.

Comment: Obrigado!! Era exatamente isso